# Regex to define the number of appearances substituted

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm breaking my head to come up with a replace regex pattern to convert

```
* foo
***** bar
*** foobar
```

to:

```
1 foo
5 bar
3 foobar
```

That is, replacing the number of appearances of the star at the beginning of each line.

So far I tried:

```
bulletpoints=/^( )*(\*)*( )+/gm
x.replace(bulletpoints, `${$2.length}`);
```

But to no avail...

Can I get some assistance?

Thank you!

Comment: `x = x.replace(/^\*+/gm, m=>m.length)`

Comment: amazing, that made the trick! thank you!